# WooCommerce - Remove product title from breadcrumbs but keep all category hyperlinks

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, breadcrumbs

I'm using the following function to remove the product title from the breadcrumbs displayed on the product page:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_breadcrumb', 'ed_change_breadcrumb' );

function ed_change_breadcrumb( $breadcrumb ) {
    
  if(is_singular()){
        array_pop($breadcrumb);
    }
  
  return $breadcrumb;
}
```

It works in that it does remove the title, but it also stops the last category/sub-category from being a hyperlink. How can I fix that?

For example:

- Original breadcrumb

  `<a>`Home`</a>` / `<a>`Category`</a>` / `<a>`Sub Category`</a>` / Product Title
- Result of the above function

  `<a>`Home`</a>` / `<a>`Category`</a>` / Sub Category

I need the Sub Category to still be clickable after removing the product title from the breadcrumbs.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code works but the last element in the breadcrumbs never contains a link through the code used in [`global/breadcrumb.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/02cf0dfaed5923513de0c88add597d1560c2cfd2/templates/global/breadcrumb.php) template file on line [34](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/02cf0dfaed5923513de0c88add597d1560c2cfd2/templates/global/breadcrumb.php#L34)

- This template can be overridden by copying it to `yourtheme/woocommerce/global/breadcrumb.php`.

---

So you can **remove your filter hook** and apply the following code in the template file so that it provides a link to the last element when `is_product()` is true

Note: [`is_product()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/) - Returns true on a single product page. Wrapper for [`is_singular()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_singular/)

Replace

```php
if ( ! empty( $breadcrumb ) ) {

    echo $wrap_before;

    foreach ( $breadcrumb as $key => $crumb ) {

        echo $before;

        if ( ! empty( $crumb[1] ) && sizeof( $breadcrumb ) !== $key + 1 ) {
            echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $crumb[1] ) . '">' . esc_html( $crumb[0] ) . '</a>';
        } else {
            echo esc_html( $crumb[0] );
        }

        echo $after;

        if ( sizeof( $breadcrumb ) !== $key + 1 ) {
            echo $delimiter;
        }
    }

    echo $wrap_after;

}
```

With

```php
if ( ! empty( $breadcrumb ) ) {

    echo $wrap_before;

    foreach ( $breadcrumb as $key => $crumb ) {

        echo $before;

        if ( ! empty( $crumb[1] ) && sizeof( $breadcrumb ) !== $key + 1 ) {
            echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $crumb[1] ) . '">' . esc_html( $crumb[0] ) . '</a>';
        } else {
            if ( is_product() ) {       
                unset($crumb);
            } else {
                echo esc_html( $crumb[0] );
            }
        }

        echo $after;

        if ( sizeof( $breadcrumb ) !== $key + 1 ) {
            if ( is_product() && sizeof( $breadcrumb ) == $key + 2 ) {
                echo '';
            } else {
                echo $delimiter;
            }
        }
    }

    echo $wrap_after;

}
```